# Not getting src folder while creating New React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, failed-installation

Node version: 12.16.2
npm version: 6.14.4

I have the following Node and npm version installed. While I try to create new react app using the command

`npx create-react-app my-app`
I do not get any src or public folder. The package.json file also seems incomplete with following code.

```
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

I tried the npm and yarn commands also for installing the react app but it doesn't work.

I also tried uninstalling create-react-app globally but it does not work either.

Comment: have you installed create-react-app? if so, why do you type 'npx'?

Comment: No, I have not installed create-react-app. I am new to react and I am following the tutorial to create react app [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) and it mentions to fire command `npx create-react-app my-app` to create new react app.

Answer (score 0):

I once faced this issue and solved with below steps as mentioned in the [github issue page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088#issuecomment-563344143).

- npm rm -g create-react-app
- npm install -g create-react-app
- npx create-react-app my-app
- also delete all the previous projects you have created and create fresh folder and try again

Also go thru Other solutions listed the page.

Comment: I have tried all the above commands. Still, no src and public folders are created. I have also checked all the other solutions listed on the page.
[link](https://prnt.sc/s3y462) This is the screenshot from my command prompt and the process does not go any further. It stops there.

Answer (score 0):

Using node 32-bit installer worked for me somehow. A 64-bit installer did not work for me. So anyone getting the same error should try using the node 32-bit installer.